# Godaddy's Code sign certificate and MIDlet

Tags: java, java-me, midp, codesign, trusted

i have developed an application in java (J2ME),
and i want trusted domain for that application using goDaddy's certificate.
can i obtain it ?
let me re describe the full scenario.
i have developed an application.in which i want FILE IO operations to be done without the permission of user (for every read write, it means user will be asked only once.)
so to obtain that i want trusted domain for my application.
for that i need to sign my application using code sign certificate.
now go Daddy's certificate is not listed under Nokia 3110Classic, so i have externally added it in CA list.
but still its showing app signing option disabled.

so my question is can i obtain trusted domain using the goDaddy's code sign certificate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an explanation about the MIDP security model, see answers to StackOverflow questions [Application Error Occurs in Nokia 6300](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497988/application-error-occurs-in-nokia-6300) and [Privileged operations in netbeans mobility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710423/privileged-operations-in-netbeans-mobility).

If the certificate you used to sign your MIDlet wasn't on the phone, just adding it to the phone may not be enough.

You probably need to add the goDaddy certificate to the MIDP runtime "trusted third party" security domain. Somehow. I'm not convinced that's possible on a Nokia 3110 Classic.

Answer (score 0):

Godaddy certificates usually depend on a Starfield certificate.  Make sure that is in place too.

Also, the app-signing might be off because you've only installed the public key.

Edit: Actually, the private key is not necessary on the box (nor desireable).  I wonder if the box is missing the Starfield certificate.

Comment: i have signed my JAD file using utility provided with NetBeans 6.8 so it certainly doesn't allow certificate without private key to sign JAD.  
Hope i am clear.

Comment: Keytool –importkeystore –srckeystore  
“The_Name_Of_The_PFX_file.PFX” –destkeystore Name_For_The_Key_store.jks –srcstoretype PKCS12 – deststoretype JKS   

I have signed using this .